# Firefox not loading my font in one web but does in another web, while Chrome does in both

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts

We're experiencing one issue with one of our webfonts and, after searching and searching, we can't find the cause.

We have one developed web application with JSP, which loads a font with the following CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    src: url('fonts/myfont-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('fonts/myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('fonts/myfont-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/myfont-webfont.svg#MyFontRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

When we have to use this font, we're calling it with:

```
.formlogin span.help-block a {
    color: #93B1CC !important;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-left: 95px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    position: relative;;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Everything ok until now (it loads ok in every browser).

Now, we're developing one another website with the same interface. So, we've copied the CSS and font files from the original to the new project.
Now, in this new project the webfont is correctly displayed in Chrome, but doesn't in Firefox and IE9.

We've tried to change the firefox property in about:config with no luck.

Both websites are using the same server, so the solution of adding anything to the server configuration doesn't solve anything.

We've tried changing the url to /fonts/.. and /styles/fonts/... and styles/fonts/... but it also didn't work.

In firebug, at network section, the URL of the font seems to be loaded correctly because it doesn't get a 404. Also in firebug, the webfont is displayed in grey (saying that it's not using it, which is obvious watching at the web). 
We've also tried to add an !important clause when calling to the webfont, but still no luck.

Any help? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

It has to be related to the paths to the files.
If I set the font-face directly with the bytes of the file, like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "MyFont";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: url("data:font/opentype;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAFaoABEAAAAA....");
}
```

It works great. Now, this is not a solution, because I should change the file depending on the browser like I was doing with the different urls in the first font-face configuration.

Anybody has any clue about the cause?

Comment: You say, "We've tried changing the url to /fonts/.. and /styles/fonts/... and styles/fonts/... but it also didn't work.", but do you know where the fonts actually are? It sounds like you're just guessing.

Comment: Sorry for give this impression, but no, we know exactly where they are. They are in the font/ folder, inside styles/ folder. The .css file is inside styles/ folder. I've added this just because in other answers some people mention to use an absolute url, but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem. 
We are using maven and the pom.xml of both projects were slightly different. No need to say that this tiny difference was the cause :D. 
In this file we had this config for the war building:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <warName>${application.context.path}</warName>
        <filters>
            <file>${project.basedir}/conf/${currentEnvironment}.properties</file>
        </filters>
        <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>pdf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.jsp</include>
                    <include>**/*.tag</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>

            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/images</directory>
                <targetPath>images</targetPath>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/scripts</directory>
                <targetPath>scripts</targetPath>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/styles</directory>
                <targetPath>styles</targetPath>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Changing, at the end, the filtering to 'false' for the styles solved the problem, because with the 'true' it was applying some security filters which avoid accessing the fonts files.